# How to not show popup again (with existing library)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, shopify

I am working on a shopify theme. It has it's own popup settings. I built a new popup for my website it is asking people to choose language when they visit the website. Until here everything is fine but when the visitor chooses language everytime the page loads they see the popup. There is a checkbox to turn it of but how can I also disable popup when they choose the language?

Checkbox which is working fine;

```html
<div class="newsletter--showAgain">
   <input id="dismiss" class="do-not-show-again" type="checkbox" name="dismiss">
   <label for="dismiss">{{ 'general.newsletter_form.dismiss' | t }}</label>
</div>
```

button that will close the popup when the visitor clicks;

```html
 <button type="button" class="selector-button" href="website">
</button>
```

I tried to put "id" and "name" inside of the button but it did not work.

ps: js file is too large to show here for close popup.

Comment: off the top of my head, I'm thinking you need to make use of a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you will have to stored the state of the checkbox to be able to retrieve it and don't show again the popup

if you want to stored this state on client side, one way can be to used `localstorage`

```
localStorage.setItem('popup-already-show', $('#dismiss').checked);
```

and in the begining of your function that open the popup check if popup already displayed

```
function openPopup() {
 if (!localStorage.getItem('popup-already-show') {
  //your code to open the popup
 }
}
```

Comment: hey @jeremy-denis thanks for your answer. So I should run a function on button click using localstorage.

Comment: yes on click on button you can play a function that update localstorage with checkbox value and recover it when popup should be display

Comment: I found this on my theme.js file @jeremy-denis;

You think can I use this by changing input to function on click ? 

 
`      $Close.on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                modal_close("#popup_newsletter", 'popup_newsletter');
                var $inputChecked = $newsLetter.find('input[name="dismiss"]').prop('checked');
                if ($inputChecked || !$newsLetter.find('input[name="dismiss"]').length)
                    $.cookie('newsLetterPopup', 'closed', {expires: $expire, path: '/'});
            });`

Sorry I cant send code

Comment: you can change the existing listener or create a new one if $close contain your button it will look like `$Close.on('click', function (event) { localStorage.setItem('popup-already-show', $('#dismiss').checked); });`